# MVC - automatically handle user notifications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, notifications

My service layer sends back a DTO with a Warning/Success/Info/Error Message to the controller, which inherits from a base controller where i handle the messages austomatically.

**I don't know if my implementation is a total nonsense and I really would like some advice!**

**DTO**

```
Public Class ExecutionResult
    Public Enum AlertType
        Warning
        Success
        Info
        [Error]
    End Enum

    Public Property Type() As AlertType
    Public Property Message() As String
End Class
```

**Base Controller:**
(with a property executionResult that I can access from every controller)

```
Public Class BaseController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnActionExecuted(ByVal ctx As ActionExecutedContext)
        Alert()
    End Sub

    Public Property executionResult As New ExecutionResult

    Public Sub Alert()
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.executionResult.Message) Then
            TempData.Add(Me.executionResult.Type, Me.executionResult.Message)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Controller:**

```
...
Inherits BaseController
...

Function SomeFunction() As ActionResult
    executionResult = _service.SomeFunctionInTheServiceLayer(viewModel)
End Function
```

**then I display the message in an partial view from the master page**

```
@For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In TempData
    If (TempData.ContainsKey(item.Key)) Then
        @<div class="alert alert-@item.Key">
            @item.Value
         </div>        
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If it works for you, and your happy with the solution, it's OK, no?

Comment: Just want to know if there is a "best practise" for this Situation, as I think everybody has to notify users somehow in MVC web apps.

Answer (score 0):

At first, i would not use TempData because it relies on SessionState which has to be enabled for all controllers to work which is not best practice because of possible performance degradation.

You don't have to store the message in Session/TempData anyway, because your View is rendered as the result of your actions. No need to store the message between requests. So ViewBag should be sufficient.

I guess you have to call your `Alert` function somewhere?
I would define a function in the basecontroller which stores the message in ViewBag (Sorry, its in C#):

```
public void SetAlert(ExecutionResult result) {
    ViewBag.Alert = result;
}
```

In your View you can simply access the ViewBag:

```
@if (ViewBag.Alert != null) {
    <div class="alert alert-@(ViewBag.Alert.Type)">
        @ViewBag.Alert.Message
     </div>        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Would'nt it be impossible to use ViewBag with a RedirectToAction call? I don't need to call the `Alert` function because I'm intercepting OnActionExecuted which relies on an public property declared in the base controller.

Comment: Yes thats right. When you want to preserve the Alert between Requests, you have to use some kind of storage.